# SimpleXML not returning anything

Tags: php, simplexml

Here's the script I'm trying to run:

```
    <?php
$lat = $_GET[lat];
$long = $_GET[long];
    $mysongs3 = simplexml_load_file('http://local.yahooapis.com/LocalSearchService/V3/localSearch?appid=845e721464167b9976ca031b0c3c66f3cc6563ee&query=restaurant&latitude='.$lat.'&longitude='.$long.'&results=2');
   $lat2 = $mysongs3->Result[0]->Latitude;
   $long2 = $mysongs3->Result[0]->Longitude;
   $mysongs4 = simplexml_load_file('http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/v1/route?key=Fmjtd%7Cluuan1urn9%2Cb0%3Do5-968206&from='.$lat.', '.$long.'&to='.$lat2.', '.$long2.'&callback=renderNarrative&outFormat=xml');
echo $mysongs4->route[0]->time;
?>
```

It doesn't echo anything.

It's utilizing the MapQuest and Yahoo API (though I know that the problem is at the MapQuest API bit, because if I remove the MapQuest bit and echo it, it works). The API key is correct, btw.

$_GET[lat] is 33.8524925 and 
$_GET[long] is -117.73242200000001 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to MapquestAPI does return the following document:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
<response>
    <info>
        <statusCode>403</statusCode>
        <messages>
            <message/>
        </messages>
        <copyright>
            <imageUrl>http://api.mqcdn.com/res/mqlogo.gif</imageUrl>
            <imageAltText>© 2012 MapQuest, Inc.</imageAltText>
            <text>© 2012 MapQuest, Inc.</text>
        </copyright>
    </info>
    <route/>
</response>
```

As you can see at the end, the `<route />` element is empty. That is why

```
echo $mysongs4->route[0]->time;
```

Is empty, too. If it would be different you would have a real problem.

If you expect there to have something, contact the API vendor for your support options.

Additionally I suggest you, that you create variables for the URLs so that you can debug which URLs you are actually requesting. Not that you have an error in building the URIs. Take care.

---

Turns out that this is actually your issue. You need to request the API with the correct URI otherwise it does not work. Double check that you remove any spaces for the `lat,long` pairs, the correct URI must look like:

```
http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/v1/route?key=Fmjtd%7Cluuan1urn9%2Cb0%3Do5-968206&from=33.8524925,-117.73242200000001&to=33.863084,-117.739601&callback=renderNarrative&outFormat=xml
```

Using that with `simplexml_load_file` works fine, see the example:

```
$mapqueryUri = 'http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/v1/route?key=Fmjtd%7Cluuan1urn9%2Cb0%3Do5-968206' .
               '&from=33.8524925,-117.73242200000001&to=33.863084,-117.739601&callback=renderNarrative' .
               '&outFormat=xml';
$mysongs4    = simplexml_load_file($mapqueryUri);
echo $mysongs4->asXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <info>
        <statusCode>0</statusCode>
        <messages/>
        <copyright>
            <imageUrl>http://api.mqcdn.com/res/mqlogo.gif</imageUrl>
            <imageAltText>© 2012 MapQuest, Inc.</imageAltText>
            <text>© 2012 MapQuest, Inc.</text>
        </copyright>
    </info>
    <route>
        <sessionId>50d7729f-0223-0013-02b7-60f4-d485645ba5f2</sessionId>
        <options>
            <shapeFormat>raw</shapeFormat>
            <generalize>-1.0</generalize>
            <maxLinkId>0</maxLinkId>
            <narrativeType>text</narrativeType>
            <stateBoundaryDisplay>true</stateBoundaryDisplay>
            <countryBoundaryDisplay>true</countryBoundaryDisplay>
            <sideOfStreetDisplay>true</sideOfStreetDisplay>
            <destinationManeuverDisplay>true</destinationManeuverDisplay>
            <avoidTimedConditions>false</avoidTimedConditions>
            <enhancedNarrative>false</enhancedNarrative>
            <returnLinkDirections>false</returnLinkDirections>
            <timeType>0</timeType>
            <routeType>FASTEST</routeType>
            <locale>en_US</locale>
            <unit>M</unit>
            <tryAvoidLinkIds/>
            <mustAvoidLinkIds/>
            <manmaps>true</manmaps>
            <drivingStyle>2</drivingStyle>
            <highwayEfficiency>22.0</highwayEfficiency>
            <useTraffic>false</useTraffic>
        </options>
        <boundingBox>
            <ul>
                <lat>33.863009999999996</lat>
                <lng>-117.741813</lng>
            </ul>
            <lr>
                <lat>33.852661</lat>
                <lng>-117.732475</lng>
            </lr>
        </boundingBox>
        <distance>1.241</distance>
        <time>272</time>
        <realTime>272</realTime>
        <fuelUsed>0.089725</fuelUsed>
        <formattedTime>00:04:32</formattedTime>
        <legs>
            <leg>
                <distance>1.241</distance>
                <time>272</time>
                <formattedTime>00:04:32</formattedTime>
                <index>0</index>
                <maneuvers>
                    <maneuver>
                        <startPoint>
                            <lat>33.8528</lat>
                            <lng>-117.7325</lng>
                        </startPoint>
                        <maneuverNotes/>
                        <distance>0.155</distance>
                        <time>34</time>
                        <formattedTime>00:00:34</formattedTime>
                        <attributes>0</attributes>
                        <turnType>6</turnType>
                        <direction>7</direction>
                        <narrative>Start out going west on E Marblehead Way toward S Hanlon Way.</narrative>
                        <directionName>West</directionName>
                        <index>0</index>
                        <streets>
                            <street>E Marblehead Way</street>
                        </streets>
                        <signs/>
                        <iconUrl><![CDATA[http://content.mapquest.com/mqsite/turnsigns/rs_left_sm.gif]]></iconUrl>
                        <linkIds/>
                        <mapUrl>
                            <![CDATA[http://www.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v4/getmap?type=map&size=225,160&pois=purple-2,33.852756,-117.732475,0,0|purple-3,33.853279,-117.73499199999999,0,0|&center=33.8530175,-117.7337335&zoom=13&key=Fmjtd|luuan1urn9,b0=o5-968206&rand=2931445&session=50d7729f-0223-0013-02b7-60f4-d485645ba5f2]]>
                        </mapUrl>
                    </maneuver>
                    <maneuver>
                        <startPoint>
                            <lat>33.8533</lat>
                            <lng>-117.735</lng>
                        </startPoint>
                        <maneuverNotes/>
                        <distance>0.521</distance>
                        <time>68</time>
                        <formattedTime>00:01:08</formattedTime>
                        <attributes>0</attributes>
                        <turnType>2</turnType>
                        <direction>2</direction>
                        <narrative>Turn right onto S Serrano Ave.</narrative>
                        <directionName>Northwest</directionName>
                        <index>1</index>
                        <streets>
                            <street>S Serrano Ave</street>
                        </streets>
                        <signs/>
                        <iconUrl><![CDATA[http://content.mapquest.com/mqsite/turnsigns/rs_right_sm.gif]]></iconUrl>
                        <linkIds/>
                        <mapUrl>
                            <![CDATA[http://www.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v4/getmap?type=map&size=225,160&pois=purple-3,33.853279,-117.73499199999999,0,0|purple-4,33.860351,-117.737342,0,0|&center=33.856815,-117.736167&zoom=10&key=Fmjtd|luuan1urn9,b0=o5-968206&rand=2546696&session=50d7729f-0223-0013-02b7-60f4-d485645ba5f2]]>
                        </mapUrl>
                    </maneuver>
                    <maneuver>
                        <startPoint>
                            <lat>33.8604</lat>
                            <lng>-117.7373</lng>
                        </startPoint>
                        <maneuverNotes/>
                        <distance>0.199</distance>
                        <time>49</time>
                        <formattedTime>00:00:49</formattedTime>
                        <attributes>0</attributes>
                        <turnType>6</turnType>
                        <direction>7</direction>
                        <narrative>Turn left onto Canyon Creek Rd.</narrative>
                        <directionName>West</directionName>
                        <index>2</index>
                        <streets>
                            <street>Canyon Creek Rd</street>
                        </streets>
                        <signs/>
                        <iconUrl><![CDATA[http://content.mapquest.com/mqsite/turnsigns/rs_left_sm.gif]]></iconUrl>
                        <linkIds/>
                        <mapUrl>
                            <![CDATA[http://www.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v4/getmap?type=map&size=225,160&pois=purple-4,33.860351,-117.737342,0,0|purple-5,33.860008,-117.740676,0,0|&center=33.8601795,-117.739009&zoom=13&key=Fmjtd|luuan1urn9,b0=o5-968206&rand=2546696&session=50d7729f-0223-0013-02b7-60f4-d485645ba5f2]]>
                        </mapUrl>
                    </maneuver>
                    <maneuver>
                        <startPoint>
                            <lat>33.86</lat>
                            <lng>-117.7407</lng>
                        </startPoint>
                        <maneuverNotes/>
                        <distance>0.163</distance>
                        <time>60</time>
                        <formattedTime>00:01:00</formattedTime>
                        <attributes>0</attributes>
                        <turnType>2</turnType>
                        <direction>1</direction>
                        <narrative>Turn right onto S Glenhurst Dr.</narrative>
                        <directionName>North</directionName>
                        <index>3</index>
                        <streets>
                            <street>S Glenhurst Dr</street>
                        </streets>
                        <signs/>
                        <iconUrl><![CDATA[http://content.mapquest.com/mqsite/turnsigns/rs_right_sm.gif]]></iconUrl>
                        <linkIds/>
                        <mapUrl>
                            <![CDATA[http://www.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v4/getmap?type=map&size=225,160&pois=purple-5,33.860008,-117.740676,0,0|purple-6,33.862079,-117.741706,0,0|&center=33.8610435,-117.74119099999999&zoom=12&key=Fmjtd|luuan1urn9,b0=o5-968206&rand=2546696&session=50d7729f-0223-0013-02b7-60f4-d485645ba5f2]]>
                        </mapUrl>
                    </maneuver>
                    <maneuver>
                        <startPoint>
                            <lat>33.8621</lat>
                            <lng>-117.7417</lng>
                        </startPoint>
                        <maneuverNotes/>
                        <distance>0.044</distance>
                        <time>20</time>
                        <formattedTime>00:00:20</formattedTime>
                        <attributes>0</attributes>
                        <turnType>2</turnType>
                        <direction>3</direction>
                        <narrative>Turn right to stay on S Glenhurst Dr.</narrative>
                        <directionName>Northeast</directionName>
                        <index>4</index>
                        <streets>
                            <street>S Glenhurst Dr</street>
                        </streets>
                        <signs/>
                        <iconUrl><![CDATA[http://content.mapquest.com/mqsite/turnsigns/rs_right_sm.gif]]></iconUrl>
                        <linkIds/>
                        <mapUrl>
                            <![CDATA[http://www.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v4/getmap?type=map&size=225,160&pois=purple-6,33.862079,-117.741706,0,0|purple-7,33.862358,-117.74101999999999,0,0|&center=33.8622185,-117.74136299999999&zoom=15&key=Fmjtd|luuan1urn9,b0=o5-968206&rand=2546696&session=50d7729f-0223-0013-02b7-60f4-d485645ba5f2]]>
                        </mapUrl>
                    </maneuver>
                    <maneuver>
                        <startPoint>
                            <lat>33.8624</lat>
                            <lng>-117.741</lng>
                        </startPoint>
                        <maneuverNotes/>
                        <distance>0.159</distance>
                        <time>41</time>
                        <formattedTime>00:00:41</formattedTime>
                        <attributes>0</attributes>
                        <turnType>2</turnType>
                        <direction>2</direction>
                        <narrative>Turn right onto E Oak Ridge Cir.</narrative>
                        <directionName>Northwest</directionName>
                        <index>5</index>
                        <streets>
                            <street>E Oak Ridge Cir</street>
                        </streets>
                        <signs/>
                        <iconUrl><![CDATA[http://content.mapquest.com/mqsite/turnsigns/rs_right_sm.gif]]></iconUrl>
                        <linkIds/>
                        <mapUrl>
                            <![CDATA[http://www.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v4/getmap?type=map&size=225,160&pois=purple-7,33.862358,-117.74101999999999,0,0|purple-8,33.863009999999996,-117.739685,0,0|&center=33.862684,-117.7403525&zoom=14&key=Fmjtd|luuan1urn9,b0=o5-968206&rand=2546696&session=50d7729f-0223-0013-02b7-60f4-d485645ba5f2]]>
                        </mapUrl>
                    </maneuver>
                    <maneuver>
                        <startPoint/>
                        <maneuverNotes/>
                        <distance>0.0</distance>
                        <time>0</time>
                        <formattedTime>00:00:00</formattedTime>
                        <attributes>0</attributes>
                        <turnType>-1</turnType>
                        <direction>0</direction>
                        <narrative>8175 E OAK RIDGE CIR is on the right.</narrative>
                        <directionName/>
                        <index>6</index>
                        <streets/>
                        <signs/>
                        <linkIds/>
                        <mapUrl><![CDATA[]]></mapUrl>
                    </maneuver>
                </maneuvers>
                <hasTollRoad>false</hasTollRoad>
                <hasFerry>false</hasFerry>
                <hasHighway>false</hasHighway>
                <hasSeasonalClosure>false</hasSeasonalClosure>
                <hasUnpaved>false</hasUnpaved>
                <hasCountryCross>false</hasCountryCross>
            </leg>
        </legs>
        <hasTollRoad>false</hasTollRoad>
        <hasFerry>false</hasFerry>
        <hasHighway>false</hasHighway>
        <hasSeasonalClosure>false</hasSeasonalClosure>
        <hasUnpaved>false</hasUnpaved>
        <hasCountryCross>false</hasCountryCross>
        <locations>
            <location>
                <street>8250 E Marblehead Way</street>
                <adminArea5 type="City">Anaheim</adminArea5>
                <adminArea3 type="State">CA</adminArea3>
                <adminArea4 type="County">Orange</adminArea4>
                <postalCode>92808</postalCode>
                <adminArea1 type="Country">US</adminArea1>
                <geocodeQuality>ADDRESS</geocodeQuality>
                <geocodeQualityCode>L1AAA</geocodeQualityCode>
                <dragPoint>false</dragPoint>
                <sideOfStreet>L</sideOfStreet>
                <displayLatLng>
                    <latLng>
                        <lat>33.852492</lat>
                        <lng>-117.732422</lng>
                    </latLng>
                </displayLatLng>
                <linkId>24154164</linkId>
                <type>s</type>
                <latLng>
                    <lat>33.852492</lat>
                    <lng>-117.732422</lng>
                </latLng>
            </location>
            <location>
                <street>8175 E Oak Ridge Cir</street>
                <adminArea5 type="City">Anaheim</adminArea5>
                <adminArea3 type="State">CA</adminArea3>
                <adminArea4 type="County">Orange</adminArea4>
                <postalCode>92808</postalCode>
                <adminArea1 type="Country">US</adminArea1>
                <geocodeQuality>ADDRESS</geocodeQuality>
                <geocodeQualityCode>L1AAA</geocodeQualityCode>
                <dragPoint>false</dragPoint>
                <sideOfStreet>R</sideOfStreet>
                <displayLatLng>
                    <latLng>
                        <lat>33.863084</lat>
                        <lng>-117.739601</lng>
                    </latLng>
                </displayLatLng>
                <linkId>24115749</linkId>
                <type>s</type>
                <latLng>
                    <lat>33.863084</lat>
                    <lng>-117.739601</lng>
                </latLng>
            </location>
        </locations>
        <locationSequence>0,1</locationSequence>
        <computedWaypoints/>
    </route>
</response>
```

Comment: The "403" error is delivered when there is an error in the code which is calling the API, according to the MapQuest API. I would like to know where the code is incorrect. When I paste the URL I'm trying to parse in the browser, it returns the directions, and the time. Thank you for your help...

Comment: @DumbProducts: The error is trivial: When you build the URI (put that to a variable so you can debug it!) for the request, you made just some little mistakes adding spaces in there. I added an example of a working URI (that is from your example data). Take care when building the URI and you're fine.

Comment: Yes double-checked! It works! Something so simple, and I couldn't find it... well that's why there are super helpful people like you, thanks again!

Comment: Use variables. When something does not work, check in-between if your expectations are met. You can see I use variables and I do `echo $...->asXML();` to verify things (I also use a debugger like Xdebug so I can stop the execution at any place and look into each variable).

Comment: And print_r works too, right, for debugging? (Correct me if I'm wrong)... I'm gonna look up Xdebug...

Comment: Yes, `print_r` and `var_dump` work as well for debugging. Sort of bare-metal kind of debugging :) Xdebug is here: http://xdebug.org/ - I can suggest to use it together with Phpstorm, a complete IDE, there is a 30 day trial: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/

Comment: Okay! Thanks so much for the tips. :) They will be much use for me... and PHPstorm works with linux yeah! :)

Comment: Yeah I love linux... You can get distros like Ubuntu that look the same or better then Mac... but why is it better for PHP? (just wondering :D)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21617/discussion-between-dumb-products-and-hakre)