# Get only domain name

Tags: javascript, php, html, server-name, http-host

i want only domain name without sub domain and path URL.

Example :

URL loading in browser : `https://www.example.com/something`. I want only `example.com`

I tried `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];` and `echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];` but the output is `www.example.com` but it want `example.com` as output.

What to use?

Comment: This isn't straightforward in terms of steps to get the exact domain name. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/14210490/4964822

Comment: `preg_replace('/^www\./','',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])` ?

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber Your code works but it only work for `www` not for all `subdomain.example.com` and every time i have to edit. i am not lazy to edit sub domains in code but there is hundreds of subdomain. how we can pick only domain name from `anything.example.com`

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber I think SERVER_NAME instead of HTTP_POST because HTTP_POST add port into url if not 80 or 443 port

Comment: You could use some other regex, for example `/^([^.]+)/`, but there are different ways to solve this.

Comment: You can do preg_replace('/^[^.]*\.(?=\w+\.\w+$)/','',$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])

Comment: `$host = preg_replace('/^[^.]*\.(?=\w+\.\w+$)/','',$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);` for own reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a check for the existing of "www." in the beginning of the string, and if the string starts with "www." I would remove it.

Example:

```
$domain = substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],0,4) === 'www.' ? substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],4) : $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
echo $domain;
```

Comment: Your code works but it only work for `www` not for all `subdomain.example.com` and every time i have to edit. i am not lazy to edit sub domains in code but there is hundreds of subdomain. how we can pick only domain name from `anything.example.com`

Comment: Ah okay - try take a look at this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679618/get-domain-name-not-subdomain-in-php . It does what you want and only return the main domain without subdomains.